# How can I switch page and fill data by a ajax request?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I use the `$.ajax` to request the data, but how can I let the page switch as the same time?

in my js:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'/api/server_payment',
    ...
    success:success_func,
})

function success_func(response){
    ...
}
```

In my views.py:

```
def server_payment(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # I don't know what to write here, because there I will switch the web page, and then fill the request data to the switched template.
```

---

**EDIT**

Because I want to pass data by the ajax to the views.py , and in the views.py I want to switch the url to a new url, and in the new url , I will render the passed data.
Because use the ajax requert I will get the response in the ajax callback function.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. If you want to go to a new page, why bother with Ajax at all?

Comment: Just process the data in your ```if request.method == 'POST':``` and if it's success, send the url you want to redirect to and then relocate to this url with js. Or make your question clearer :).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because the ajax request is in a callback method.

Comment: @Bestasttung See my edit, my friend, because I want to redirect a new url, and render the ajax passed data to the new url template.

Comment: You can pass the data as query params  onto new url I think that's the best way.

Comment: @NakulNarayanan Because in django, only render can fill the data to the template, use ajax to request the new url, in views.py only can return HttpResponse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just pass your data from ajax to the views with the post data:

**file.js**

```
data = {
  'key': value,
  'another_key': another_value,
  // as many as you need
  ...
}
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'/api/server_payment',
    data: data
    ...
    success:success_func,
})

function success_func(response){
    ...
}
```

Now in your view server_payment store them in the session :

```
def server_payment(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.session['key'] = request.POST.get('key')
        request.session['another_key'] = request.POST.get('another_key')
        ...
        return HttpRedirectResponse('/other/url')
```

And now in your other views (corresponding to the one at  '/other/url', you'll access to the data in `request.session`. In the other views, get data by poping them to empty the `request.session` dict :

**views.py rendering the data**

```
def another_view(request):
    data = {}
    data['key'] = request.session.pop('key', "NOT_FOUND")  # this will prevent from raising exception
    data['another_key'] = request.session.pop('another_key', "NOT_FOUND")
    ...

    return render('/your/template.html', data)
```

> I want to pass data by the ajax to the views.py , and in the views.py I want to switch the url to a new url, and in the new url , I will render the passed data.

The thing I don't understand is why you don't send your post data directly in the good view to render instead of having a view getting the post data and redirecting to another one.

Comment: If I use ajax to request, whether I can not return render(request, 'xxx/template.html')? because it do not skip web page.